# cleartool - merging single proc

Tags: merge, clearcase, cleartool

I am trying to merge a single proc from a branch `Nov12` to `main`. After searching in this reference I found the following should merge a copy from the branch to the main

```
Merge version 1 on the branch into the "latest" version in the "main" branch:
ct merge -to new_update.sql -insert -version /main/Nov12/1
```

After running this I got the output as

```
Trivial merge: "new_update.sql" is same as base "/home/mtk/ct/new_update.sql@@/main/Nov12/0".
Copying "/home/mtk/ct/new_update.sql @@/main/Nov12/1" to output file.
Output of merge is in "new_update.sql.merge".
```

the `new_update.sql.merge` contains the complete proc on local disk, it's not in the clearcase version control. I did a `ct lsh` to verify this.

I wanted it should have created a new version on the main and placed the updated copy into it i.e. /main/9 which not yet exists. The latest `/main` version is 8.

So, how to merge a single proc. Do we need to checkout a copy from the main and then run the above command. Please let me know, I am not clear on this. I need a command line solution for this, as graphical alternative is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be in a view set to create version on `/main`.
Instead, your merge wanted to create a version on `Nov12`

The page "[To merge selective versions from a subbranch](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_merge_select_branch.htm)" details the merge you are using:

```
cleartool merge [ -graphical ] -to target-path -insert contributor-version-selector  [contributor-version-selector]
```

But it also requires to **check out the *target version* first**.
That means that, even before your merge, you should see in the version tree a version created after your `/main/8` one.

So try again your merge in the right target view, the one made to make new version on `/main`.

Comment: So, do I need to delete my answer because I'm just misleading?  Or confusing?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the key point of your answer is the same as mine: check your target view. The `findmerge` (especially with `-fver` option: the OP might not have set any tag) is a nice alternative, so I would like to see your answer stay.

Comment: @VonC You are correct. I am not in the correct view. Thanks that helped correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the trouble is that you didn't specify where the output was to go, so it was put in the file `new_update.sql.merge`, assuming that the current view has a cspec set to your target branch, `/main`.  (If your view doesn't reference the `/main` branch, you're merging in the wrong view.)  You can now do:

```
mv new_update.sql.merge new_update.sql
```

and then make the check-in, assuming that either you or ClearCase did the necessary checkout.

---

That isn't the way I customarily do merges — but that isn't to say it is invalid.  The mechanism I use is `ct findmerge` and then run the commands from the log file.  I'd have two views, one with a cspec for the Nov12 branch (the view tag might be `nov12`), the other (the current view) with a cspec for the main branch.

```
ct findmerge -ftag nov12 new_update.sql
```

The output might include lines like:

```
Needs Merge "./samizdat.c" [(automatic) to /main/XYZ.1.70/0 from /main/XYZ.1.70
    /TEMP.bug233636.jleffler/1 (base also /main/XYZ.1.70/0)]
```

This will generate a log file with a name like:

```
findmerge.log.2012-11-27T23:12:43-08:00
```

The contents of the file is commands like:

```
cleartool findmerge ./samizdat.c -fver /main/XYZ.1.70/TEMP.bug233636.jleffler/1 -log /dev/null -merge -cqe
```

The `-merge` means 'non-graphical merge' (`-gmerge` for graphical); the `-cqe` means 'query for comments for each check-out' (I always replace that with `-c "Bug 233636: Brief title for bug"`).

I doubt if it is the quickest possible way of doing business, but it does work for me.  I've disguised file and branch names, but assuming I get my review approved, that's (more or less) how I'll be doing a merge and check-in of about 20 files for a mini (micro?) feature.  I have cover scripts to drive a lot of this stuff, so my command sequence will actually be:

```
fmp -l log 233636 /vobs/project/ /vobs/auxilliary
fmm log
ct ci -c 'Bug 233636: Brief title for bug' $(ct lsco -avo -cvi -s)
```

The `fmp` (find merge and print) script runs the first `findmerge` with the output going to the file `log`.  The `fmm` (find merge and merge) script does the actual merging, and automatically provides the last check-in message for the files to be merged.  The last line does the check-in with my chosen comment (`ct` is an alias for `cleartool`), overriding the comment provided by `fmm`.

Comment: Whoa, I now understand why you are still in front of me in the query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/8782/users-who-post-long-answers (use 5000 posts) ;)

Comment: And I don't think `findmerge` is required here. Yet, it is a valid alternative, so +1.

Comment: Oooh; I post longer posts on average than anyone else?  And not very effectively, since my rep/character is lower than most.  You'd best get busy typing another 1.3 MB of answer...  (Interesting; the standard deviation on the length of my posts is larger than my average post!)

Comment: Yes, I have always found that query... fascinating ;)

Comment: You're correct that `findmerge` is probably not necessary.  However, it is the way I always work because there is less chance of me missing one file in some sundry VOB when I've made changes in 6 directories in 3 VOBs.

Comment: I agree, and find that answer a good opportunity to document and illustrate the `findmerge` command. So, it is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :) I find this useful +1.